# Is it possible to use Socialauth without Spring/Struts/Seam?

Tags: oauth, socialauth

I would like to avoid any lock-in and it seems to me that [Socialauth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) is limited to the major frameworks, is there a way to use it in other frameworks (or no framework).
e.g. I would like to be able to use it in Play / Lift etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a framework to use the Socialauth.
See [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStartedWithYourOwnFramework).